# Flutter - Cannot copy file to new path

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to copy the image to the application directory, but I always get this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled
>   exception: E/flutter ( 4159): FileSystemException: **Cannot copy file** to
>   '/data/user/0/com.vendetta.recipe/app_flutter', path =
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.vendetta.recipe/files/Pictures/a6fd32a9-60b2-4cff-8f10-2ffc2933bf751208556873045090039.jpg'
>   (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21) E/flutter ( 4159): #0
>   _File.copy. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:340:9) E/flutter ( 4159): #1      _RootZone.runUnary
>   (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54) E/flutter ( 4159): #2
>   _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18) E/flutter ( 4159): #3
>   Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45) E/flutter ( 4159): #4
>   Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
>   E/flutter ( 4159): #5      Future._completeWithValue
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:486:5) E/flutter ( 4159): #6
>   Future._asyncComplete.
>   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:516:7) E/flutter ( 4159): #7
>   _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21) E/flutter ( 4159): #8      _startMicrotaskLoop
>   (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)

I want to copy this image, to be sure, when I save it, that the user is not deleting an important file. This file I wanted to store inside the database.

This is the code where I copy the image, that was taken with [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker):

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = directory.path;
File newImage = await _image.copy('$path');
```

I hope somebody is able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`path` is the directory `/data/user/0/com.vendetta.recipe/app_flutter`. Try adding a `/filename.jpg` to it.

```
File newImage = await _image.copy('$path/filename.jpg');
```

Comment: Hey, this throws an error in Android 10, errno 13, permission denied

Comment: the user needs to give you access to write to some directories

Comment: Wait, do u mean that I need to ask user storage access everytime? As of now, I ask for the permission when the app is opened

Comment: But I'm getting the error, even if I have already asked for user permission. The solution I found was to compilesdk at 29, and add "allowLegacyExternalStorage" as true in Android manifest.xml. I learnt that this is due to scoped storage in Android 10, but how to use the external storage directory from now onwards?

Comment: @NithinSai are you found solution i am also facing this issue

Comment: @Adnanhaider in android 10, as i mentioned, u need to add legacy support in manifest ```android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"```, from android 11 onwards, u need to use scoped storage it self. Refer docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 4):

Please try this then your problem is resolved

I have provided to you can also copy file of any extension dynamically

Follow these steps -

1.First add this import

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
```

2.Get file name with extension

```
 var basNameWithExtension = path.basename(sourceFile.path);
```

3.Then pass the extension to the

```
var file =  await moveFile(sourceFile,newPath+"/"+basNameWithExtension);
```

4.Then Write this method

```
Future<File> moveFile(File sourceFile, String newPath) async {
    try {
      /// prefer using rename as it is probably faster
      /// if same directory path
      return await sourceFile.rename(newPath);
    } catch (e) {
      /// if rename fails, copy the source file 
      final newFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);
      return newFile;
    }
  }
```

5. Then you will get expected result

Comment: Hey, does this Delete the original file?

Comment: i want to use copy or move my file to one directory to another how can i do that
here is my file path '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.wasisoft.topi/files/video1.mp4' and here i want to move my file path  '/storage/emulated/0/Download/video1.
mp4',